# HG4Idea hangs on windows

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

[image]Has anybody else had an issue with the new Intellij HG4IDEA not working in Windows?  Whenever I try to pull from a remote repository it just hangs, never asking for my ssh username/password.

My initial thought was that I should set my username/password in mercurial.ini somehow.

It just sits like this indefinably, if I try to cancel it it will not stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get Intellij 10 to work with hg4idea I just changed my mercurial.ini file in my user directory of windows.

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg setting dialog

[extensions]
hgext.convert=

[ui]
username = myusername

[trusted]
users = *
groups = *


[ui]
ssh="C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\bin\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

The key was to set ssh= to a client that supports prompting for passwords.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure it to work with your keys without password or
use ssh client that is able to ask password in a dialog window, like
TortoisePlink.exe.

When using console SSH client, there is no way for IDEA to see if it's
requesting passwords and provide them (it's just not supported, so ssh
client must either work without asking anything in the console or ask
a password via dialog).

See also
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-62230 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-56004.